# knex: what is the appropriate way to create an array from results?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I have an endpoint that joins the `user` and `user_emails` table as a one-to-many relationship (postgresql). It look as follows.

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  db.select('users.id', 'users.name', 'user_emails.address')
    .from('users')
    .leftJoin('user_emails', 'users.id', 'user_emails.user_id')
    .then(users => res.status(200).json(users))
    .catch(next)  // go to error handler
});
```

However, this will return a new document for each email address. What I want is an array of documents that looks as follows:

```
[{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Steve',
  emails: [
    { address: 'hello@world.org' },
    { address: 'meow@meow.org' }
  ]
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'Jimmy',
  emails: [
    { address: 'jimmy@jimbo.org' }
  ]
}]
```

How should this be done in knex?

Comment: if i understand correctly , you're getting 1 row for each address but you want it to be nested to 'name'?

Comment: nested into `emails` as an array but yes

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Assuming you're using Postgres - you need to use `array_agg` function to generate arrays. I would suggest using knex.raw

Please let me know if this works.

```
   knex('users')
    .innerJoin('user_emails','users.id','user_emails.user_id')
    .select([
      'users.id as userID',
      'users.name as userName',
      knex.raw('ARRAY_AGG(user_emails.adress) as email')
    ])
    .groupBy('users.id','users.name')
```

Comment: Works absolutely perfectly! Thank you! Although, if you happen to know, can this be used to make an array of objects?

Comment: if you're talking about creating an array of json objects , postgres 9.4 and above support the use of json_object(col 1, col 2).

Comment: Ah, that worked, but lead to a nifty link for `json_build_object` as well

Comment: For some reason, I am getting only one value in the array. What could be the reason for that?