# Node - Knex to return array of objects as a result of joined tables

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I am using knexjs and node and running postgres db with this tables: menu and menuItem having one-to-many relationship. I found a solution here [knex: what is the appropriate way to create an array from results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37255577/knex-what-is-the-appropriate-way-to-create-an-array-from-results/37279036?fbclid=IwAR3szQgDYhFWTITgZC7eBRg8CyFO2KM91T-zH2MVdRGAMopPzmMUe05amd4) however this returns an array of strings. What i need is to return an array of objects and an empty array if null that looks exactly as the example below:

```
[
  {
    id: 123,
    name: 'Sunday Menu',
    items: []
  }, 
  {
    id: 456,
    name: 'Monday Menu',
    items: [
      { 
         id: 987,
         name: 'Fried Chicken',
         pcs: 69
      },
      { 
         id: 876,
         name: 'Egg Soup',
         pcs: 50
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

My menu and menuItem table schema looks similar to this:

```
menu_table: {
  id,
  name,
  timestamps
}
```

```
menuItem_table: {
  id,
  menu_id,
  name,
  pcs,
  timestamps
}
```

Currently, my code is like this:

```
knex('menu').leftJoin('menuitem', 'menu.id', 'menuitem.menu_id')
.select(['menu.id as menuID', knex.raw('ARRAY_AGG(menuitem.name) as items')])
.groupBy('menu.id')
```

And here's the result:

```
[
  {
     "menuID": "20091fff-ca8b-42d6-9a57-9f6e1922d0fa",
     "items": [
         null
     ]
  },
  {
     "menuID": "2ddad4fa-7293-46c5-878f-cb2881be3107",
     "items": [
         "Fried Chicken",
         "Egg Soup",
         "Vegetable Dish"
     ]
  }
]
```

UPDATE: I found out how to do it using raw query how ever i can't translate it using knex. Here's my code:

```
SELECT menu.*, COALESCE(menuitem.items, '[]') AS items FROM menu LEFT JOIN LATERAL ( 
   SELECT json_agg(menuitem.*) AS items FROM menuitem WHERE menu.id = menuitem.menu_id 
) menuitem ON true
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: I currently tried this: `knex('menu').leftJoin('menuitem', 'menu.id', 'menuitem.menu_id').select(['menu.id as menuID', knex.raw('ARRAY_AGG(menuitem.name) as items')]).groupBy('menu.id')` and returning `items: ['Fried Chicken', 'Egg Soup']`

Comment: Add that to your question. It's one of the things that can make your question valid and not closed as a do-my-homework type question

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution to my question. Since I was able to get my desired result thru raw query, i just translate it to knex. My final code is this:

```
const coalesce = knex.raw(`coalesce(menuitem.items, '[]') as items`)
const sub = knex('menuitem').select(knex.raw('json_agg(menuitem.*) as items')).whereRaw('menu.id = menuitem.menu_id')

return knex('menu').select(['menu.*', coalesce]).joinRaw('left join lateral ? menuitem on true', sub)
```

I'm gonna go with this code in the mean time until someone would give me the most accurate answer.

Comment: One down side of that is that the rows are converted to json types before they are returned from database. So for example custom de serializations done by pg-types will not work.

Comment: Will take note of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This work, im add attachments, ty DevWannabe :

```
const results = await knex.column({
  'id': 'str.id',
  'projectName': 'str.project_name',
})
.from('venturedoor.startups as str')
.leftJoin('venturedoor.attachments as att', 'str.id', 'att.startup_id')
// join array attachments
.select(['str.id', knex.raw('ARRAY_AGG(att.*) as attachments')])
.groupBy('str.id')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
knex.raw('coalesce(usr.userName,usr.email ,seat.username) as username')
```

We can use like that measn. If userName is empty so will call email if email also then will call name from seats.